# Wordpress/Elementor функция the_content

Tags: wordpress

Плагин Elementor не открывает главную страницу. Вылазит ошибка "Вы должны вызвать функцию the_content в текущем шаблоне". Другие станицы открываются. Это случилось при переносе сайта с локалки. На локалке все шикарно работает. Подскажи пожалуйста где вызвать эту функцию?

Comment: Если на локалке работало, а на сервер не работает, то, скорее всего, перенесли неправильно. Почитайте о том, как правильно переносить сайт на WP: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Answer (score 1):

Общих причин для the_content не называть

Есть три распространенных события, которые могут быть причиной того, почему the_content не будет вызываться:

Иногда у темы есть шаблон главной страницы, который уже подготовлен и не содержит контент со страницы. Это наиболее распространено в бесплатных темах WordPress.

Пользовательские шаблоны страниц, которые не включают в себя параметр_content.
Страницы продуктов WooCommerce и страницы магазина WooCommerce, которые не включают the_content.

Добавьте функцию the_content в код шаблона страницы.

Это строка, которую вы должны добавить: `<? Php the_content (); ?>`

Если вы не знакомы с тем, где разместить этот код или как его добавить на страницу, обратитесь к разработчику своего веб-сайта, чтобы он мог быть правильно реализован, поскольку мы не можем обеспечить полную поддержку этого. Обратите внимание, что добавление этого кода не позволит редактировать страницы архива и страницы последних сообщений.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение:** Настройки - Чтение - Страница записей - уберите оттуда вашу страницу (т.е. выбираем только "Главная страница", а для "Страница записей" оставьте -Выбрать-). Если вы выберите страницу записей ту, которую сделали в elementor, он будет считать это шаблоном archive и выводить эту ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто зайти в редактирование страницы и заменить шаблон страницы на элементор)
НО возможно, что придется править стили.